# "経験になる" difference with "経験ということになる"?

Tags: nuances, nominalization

What is the difference in nuance between:

> (1) 今は、私にとっては大学卒業式に最も近い経験**ということ**になっている。

and

> (2) 今は、私にとっては大学卒業式に最も近い経験になっている。

Personally, I'd always say #2. Is there a context when #2 is absolutely wrong? too unnatural?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sentence (2) is the neutral one.

～ということになっている is a set phrase meaning "(externally) is said to be ～", "allegedly is ～". If you use Sentence (1), people will wonder if there is another event in your mind which was closer to the 大学卒業式.

Comment: wow. That fix exactly into the context of what I am reading!